# Парсинг Selenium+ bs4 Python. Ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, bs4

Я новичок в парсинге. Есть задача: проверить, имеющиеся УНП компаний (файл csv, который переводится в список по ходу кода) по Единому государственному регистру (сайт: https://egr.gov.by/egrn/index.jsp?content=Find) и узнать актуальное состояние (Действующее, в ликвидации и т.д), выгрузить его в виде файла.
Вот мой код

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

CSV = 'Статус'

def get_content(browser):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    orgs = soup.findAll('table', class_='mb-6')
    cards = []

    for org in orgs:
        cards.append(
            {
                    'unp': org.find_all('td')[5].get_text(),
                    'state': org.find_all('td')[1].get_text()
            }
        )

    return cards

def save_doc(orgs, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Статус', 'УНП'])
        for org in orgs:
            writer.writerow([org['unp'], org['state']])

def parser():
    i = 0
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://egr.gov.by/egrn/index.jsp?content=Find")

    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Наташа\\UNP.csv")
    print(data)
    UNP_spisok = data['Код налогоплательщика'].tolist()
    print(UNP_spisok)

    cards = []

    while i<len(UNP_spisok):
        print("Парсим UNP: ", i,  UNP_spisok[i])
        search_input = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "name")
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "name")))
        for k in range(0, 9):
            search_input.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)

        search_input.send_keys(str(UNP_spisok[i]) +"\n")

        cards.extend(get_content(browser))
        save_doc(cards, CSV)

        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Парсинг закончен")

    browser.close()

parser()
```

При запуске кода, возникает ошибка (через разное количество выполненных циклов):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\Poisk.py", line 72, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\Poisk.py", line 59, in parser
    save_doc(cards, CSV)
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Наташа\PycharmProjects\pythonParsing\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C94C3E62+57250]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C943BC02]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C930DF6D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C9342BD4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C9341F94]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C93667AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C933E536]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C93669C0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C937E312]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C9366583]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C933CC71]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C933DE54]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C9774CF2+2879026]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C97C6F30+3215472]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C97BFD4F+3186319]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7C9555505+652869]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C9447518]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C94435F4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C94436EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF7C94338E3]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC1F2F7614+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC1FC026B1+33]
```

Я уже пыталась выставлять и time.sleep на 5-20 с в нескольких местах (после удаления уже проверенного УНП из поля и перед поиском информации из таблицы), пробовала применять WebDriverWait, но тут есть проблема. Иногда ошибка возникает из-за того, что таблица с результатом не успевает загрузиться на сайте. Если выставить WebDriverWait перед стадией считывания информации с этой таблицы, то программа завершится при первом УНП, которое не будет найдено на данном сайте.

Кусок кода разработчика для таблицы
[image: Кусок кода разработчика для таблицы]

Кусок кода разработчика в случае, когда информации нет
[image: Кусок кода разработчика в случае, когда информации нет]

В связи с этим вопрос: может кто-нибудь сталкивался с ситуацией, когда нужно применить WebDriverWait и есть два возможных элемента, которые могут появится?
Буду очень благодарна за ответ, уже всю голову себе сломала.
Заранее, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Система time.sleep не всегда оправдана. Обычно стараются заменить такой конструкцией:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, "/html/body/a/span"))).click()
```

ну там на вкус и цвет XPATH или же By.class и т.д. В зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: Да, я пробовала конструкцию WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "name"))) относительно таблицы с нужной информацией, только программа прерывалась в тот момент, когда проверялся УНП, которого нет в ЕГР (т.е. по нем нет таблицы с нужной информацией, а вместо нее возникает другой объект - надпись "По данному запросу ничего не найдено". Как можно установить это ожидание на появление одного или другого объекта? Чтобы программа не прерывалась, когда не найдет таблицу, а просто оставила это поле пустым.

Comment: В зависимости, что вы имеете (ошибку отдельной строкой, каким то событием, или новой строкой). Просто обрабатывать эту ошибку. Заверните в try.  Или если это текст на самой странице. Парсить кусок элемента на наличие записи("По данному запросу ничего не найдено").

Comment: Спасибо. Использовала try, подставила ожидание, а на случай появления ошибки (ожидаемой, если этот элемент не находит), поставила ожидание появления второго элемента.